# Unable to use images from the img folder in pyhon app using a html template with Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit, langchain, python-templates

I am new to Python and I have been unable to use images from the img folder in my python app using a html template include. The image src that uses an external link works fine. Is there a lib or module or something I need to add to make the image for the local folder show on the page like the other image produced from the external link.

Code below

```
bot_template = '''
<div class="chat-message bot">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cN0nmSj/Screenshot-2023-05-28-at-02-37-21.png" 
style="max-height: 78px; max-width: 78px; border-radius: 50%; object-fit: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="message">{{MSG}}</div>
</div>
'''

user_template = '''
<div class="chat-message user">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="/img/ghog1.jpg" >
    </div>    
    <div class="message">{{MSG}}</div>
</div>
'''
```

Comment: The source of the issue can be on a few different places.  
- MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL need to be set in your settings
- You template file needs to include {% static %} and image referred to with static tag.
Both of these doc pages should be able to help you on your way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/files/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: TY SD! When you said to look a django, I did and then I realized when it was a web framework. I was using Streamlit as the web framework. I then went the doc there and they have a setting in the .streamlit/config.toml where you add the line for the ability to serve static out of a "static" folder. TY again even if they were different frameworks it made me realize what I had to do.

Comment: Glad it helped @imtryin2code, must admit I missed the point where you're using another framework.  Not sure why I was assuming you're not using django. But happy it helped!

Comment: I had not mentioned it SD so you wouldnt have known. I should have been more detailed in my question. I will make sure to add info like that in future.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Streamlit as the web framework. I went to the doc at Streamlit and they have a setting in the .streamlit/config.toml where you add the line for the ability to serve static out of a "static" folder.

```
# .streamlit/config.toml located in your %USER% root folder

[server]
enableStaticServing = true

# app.py

import streamlit as st

with st.echo():
    st.tiltle("Cat")

    st.markdown("[![Click Me](app/static/myimage.png)](https://streamlit.io)")
```